Mod using their powers to unilaterally reopen their own closed question
This is in reference to a moderator's handling of a question they had posted.
After the moderator asked the question, it was poorly received and closed by receiving 5 votes from the community. The moderator then unilaterally reopened the question using their moderator powers. The question is now closed again, but I still think this actions merits discussion.
This is a real problem. A moderator still needs to follow the rules of the site, and should not be using their powers to reopen questions (especially their own questions) after users have voted to close it. Are there site guidelines about this?

Why remove the link to the question?

Probably because they were told to not make reference to any particular user, so they removed anything that would point to anything specific? (I'm guessing here).

@JonathanZ Yes this is why

For the record: I was the one who closed it again.
Being a moderator is still new to me. By force of habit, I voted to reopen the question; I did not intend to "unilaterally reopen" it.

Most of us aren't mods, so to clarify: When you become a mod, the button that used to mean "vote to reopen" now means "unilaterally reopen"?

Yes, @JonathanZ

Your candidness is appreciated. Such things happen.

I appreciate knowing that it wasn't intentional (I am interested in the discussion still about whether there are policies about this kind of thing).

@Gerry  Facts support you - he did not immediately reclose it when he saw his vote unilaterally reopened it (impossible to miss), but instead waited 12 hours (by which time there was much uproar) - see the timeline.  But there is definitely  a learning curve for new mods - even when it comes to how they must adjust their personal views on site policy (Shaun's diverge from the norm in many ways). Hopefully they'll change to convergent as time passes....

I was asleep! ${}$

@Shaun Why didn't you immediately reclose it before you went to sleep? You can't have missed that your vote immediately reopened it. since that occurs instantaneously.

I don't know, @BillDubuque.

I dropped the ball. Sorry.

Best of luck climbing the diamond-mod learning curve. Every mod has to do so. For some it is more steep than others, but as long as you continually make an effort to learn from your mistakes  all should go well.

It's not entirely clear to me why someone would want to close the question in the first place. You were looking for a reference. What else were you expected to write? "My attempt: I looked in standard textbooks X, Y, Z but couldn't find this result. Then I asked a colleague who specializes in number theory who didn't have a reference offhand. Then I tried google searching and after 20 minutes I gave up so I decided to post a question here." It seems kind of silly to include this.

@mechanodroid I disagree. I someone asks me for a reference, I first check some standard sources. It's pointless for potential answerers to maybe even go to the library and get physical copies of books which the OP has already checked. So giving a list of references you have checked already is actually useful context for potential answerers

@MaoWao I concede that stating the books you already checked is useful to include in the question. I'm inquiring about the fact that some people seemingly deem it necessary to include. Why is not mentioning a few books you checked (out of probably hundreds of relevant books) enough to close the question?

@mechanodroid That's really beside the point. You might not find the reason clear, but other people did and voted accordingly. If you want clarification on this, it could be a separate Meta question.

Can we get a clarification on the policy mods have for taking actions on their own posted Q's and A's?
I'm pretty sure I've seen a mod say they wouldn't edit or close a post that discussed their actions (rather unkindly), as they felt there was no way to appear disinterested. (This was on meta.)
I also know that I don't do any "moderation type actions" on things I post, for a similar reason. Although maybe I just can't because the UI prevents me. I don't know; I've never tried to upvote one of my own answers, nor vote to re-open one of my questions.
Is there any policy, either formalized across the site, or informally agreed, for moderators?
(Language note: "Disinterested" means "not having a reason to personally gain or lose in a dispute", and is different from "uninterested". It's a distinction that even many native English speakers don't get - sorry to rely on this distinction, but I think it's important to the issue at hand.)

This is not really an answer to the question, but it a new question.  I would suggest that you first search meta to see if this has come up before (I would guess that it has, but I don't know off the top of my head), and then post this as a new meta question.
